# set relative Layout without hard Coded value android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

hello i had problem in layout my layout is fit for all screen when i set it in linear Layout but the problem in linear Layout is that when i bring View to front it disturb other views now i change the required layout to relative Layout in which i also bring view to front which work perfect but now the problem is in relative layout is hard coded values for different screen resolutions so what can i do for this any one help me please and Thanks in advance.........

here is my layout code ....

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

               <LinearLayout 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_weight=".8"
                android:background="@drawable/prdttrans">
                </LinearLayout>


               <RelativeLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_weight=".2"

                  >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/animimage" 
                android:background="@drawable/ab"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/waterleftDisplayimg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="39dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/waterrightdisplayimg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/waterleftDisplayimg"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"<-------------- these hardcoded values  
   cause problems 
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

   </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

i want to set relative Layout on all screen

Comment: can you please post image how your layout look like ?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not getting what are you actually trying to say.

Comment: Harish sorry i had low reputation.......

Comment: Rashid i want to set relative layout for all screen resolution in relative layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hardcode for multiple screens, you can use `dimens`.

Under `values` folder in your resources, create (if not exists) an xml named `dimens.xml` which will look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
    <dimen name="left_margin_value">20dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Create dimens files for different screen resolutions, and set your desired dp values according to these screens. Example screens:

```
res/values/dimens.xml as default
res/values-sw360dp/dimens.xml
res/values-sw480dp/dimens.xml
res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml
res/values-sw720dp/dimens.xml
res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml
```

After creating and settings those files, in your layout xml file, change `ImageView` margin like this:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin_value"
```

Comment: well of course it will work. you are going to set different dp values for different screens like 20dp, 40dp, 80dp whatever, and in according devices with those screensizes, you will see that value. You can look here for further help about supporting screen sizes: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: ok i am try to my best if your method work for me i will accept your answer and thanks for logical answer

Comment: well i will create different layout files hmmm

Comment: no, not different layout files. It is an option as well, but what I suggested is, creating different dimension files, and set this dimen value to your single layout.

Comment: sir your method is creative but i m not getting you how i will set differnt dimention file in single layout......... can you explain breafly ..........

Comment: I already explained. You will write android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin_value" as your left margin. And then, according to the device size, it will look to specific dimens.xml file and set the value from there. Example: values-sw360dp/dimens.xml will have 30dp, values-sw480dp/dimens.xml will have 40dp inside. if the device is sw360, it will use 30dp, if it is sw480, it will use 40dp as margin value.

Comment: Not really interesting :) if you want to support multiple screens and you just have to change some sizes and margins, creating dimens files and setting it in 1 layout is the easiest way. You can create multiple layout files too when needed but for your question, it is not necessary.

Comment: sir can you suggest values folder name that support differnt resoution i have only values-SW600 and values-SW720-land

Comment: i mean to say sir that help me out in values folder name for different screen inches